# how to schedule local notification every day 10 o'clock in windows phone app RT

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, schedule, localnotification

I want to schedule local notification everyday 10 o'clock.

```
DateTime EventDate = new DateTime(2016, 02, 11, 17, 52, 20);
            TimeSpan NotTime = EventDate.Subtract(DateTime.Now);
            DateTime dueTime = DateTime.Now.Add(NotTime);

            ScheduledToastNotification scheduledToast = new ScheduledToastNotification(content, dueTime);
            ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().AddToSchedule(scheduledToast);
```

but what happend is in the above code perticuler date and  time has given. but I want to everyday 10 o'clock schedule the notification.how to schedule please help me.

Answer (score 0):

[Background task](http://www.romasz.net/how-to-add-a-backgroundtask/) are helpful in this case. And in background task you can check current Time with 10:00 clock and do your necessary logic.